# how do I set the logging level to info for MongoDb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, logging, mongoid

I have a Rails app that uses MongoDb on the back. I have these messages that say `MONGODB [WARNING] Please note that logging negatively impacts client-side performance. You should set your logging level no lower than :info in production` in my logs. OK, I never worried about it but decided to look it up just now.

[This page on the mongo site](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Logging) doesn't really discuss logging levels, but it does discuss `-v` vs `-vvvv` for verbosity. Is that the same thing as log level? As in `-vvvvv` is the same as a debug log level and `-v` is the same as an error log level? The docs are very unclear on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging levels refer to rails logging levels whereas the -v flag refers to verbosity.

Rails automatically sets the logging level higher in production than when in development so you shouldn't have anything to worry about.

Comment: I'm not sure that's it -- I updated the OP. The message specifically states that its from MONGODB and there's a lot of Mongo messages in my log like `MONGODB the_database['users'].find({:deleted_at=>nil, :deleted=>nil})`. I wonder if this is coming from Mongoid.

Comment: It looks like this is coming from the Mongo ruby driver: http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Logging.html# (in the source).

Comment: Ok is this in the production or development?

Comment: @TylerBrock I think the answer to my question is: don't bother with mongodb for this warning message, the message is unclear, just worry about the logging level in the app.

Answer (score 7):

I had problems with this in my tests, so I ended up doing the following in my spec_helper.rb:

```
Mongoid.logger.level = Logger::INFO
```

However if you are inside of rails you should probably (untested) use this to access the logger instead:

```
config.mongoid.logger
```

Comment: This was exactly my problem, I had log messages dumping to stdout when running rspec with mongoid + sinatra. Thanks!

Comment: Here's the link to [the documentation for this](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#logging)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using mongoid 2.2 or higher, you can set it in mongoid.yml:

```
production:
  hosts:
    ...
  database: ...
  logger: false
```

Also, this *does* have a performance impact.  When I turned off mongo logging in production, I saw fewer garbage collections and app instance memory footprints were about 15 megabytes smaller during 30-minute load tests using apachebench.