# Mongoid code not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

The following code works in development like a charm, but in production no update is ever issued to the database. Basically I am trying to update a collection element that is nested 3 levels deep ..

```
def set_collection_value                                                                                                                                                                          
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])                                                                                                                                                            
    @article.highlights.items.find(params[:item_id])                                                                                                                                                              
    item.update_attributes(params[:values])                                                                                                                                                         

    render :json => item                                                                                                                                                                            
  end
```

The model Article in question looks like this:

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_one :highlight, class_name: 'Highlight'
end
```

`highlight.rb`

```
class Highlight
  includes Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :article

  embeds_many :items, class_name: 'HighlightElement'
end
```

`highlight_item.rb`

```
class HighlightElement                                                                                                                                                                              
  include Mongoid::Document                                                                                                                                                                         

  embedded_in :highlight                                                                                                                                                                            

  field :title, type: String                                                                                                                                                                        
  field :teaser, type: String                                                                                                                                                                       
  field :image, type: String                                                                                                                                                                        
  field :body, type: String                                                                                                                                                                         

  attr_accessible :title, :teaser, :image, :body                                                                                                                                                    
end
```

The funny thing here is that even when I run webrick locally in production mode it works like a charm. Only once I deploy to my ubuntu server running mongodb v1.2.2 the above code silently does nothing.

I even went as far as to copy my `environments/development.rb` onto my `environments/production.rb` hoping to fix the issue.. but to no avail..

Any ideas? I am running rails 3.2.7 with mongoid 3.0.3

It would also be helpful if someone could point out how to make the moped/mongoid debug log messages show up in production.log. I configured Debugging [as described in the logs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#logging) - but these debug messages are only visible when running rails s - not in `production.log`

Comment: Logs? I suspect there's no connection to the db. What about a read only page, is /article/1 (a guess) showing an article?

Comment: Yes.. everything else works fine.. I can even set values through other methods.. Just this one is not working..

Comment: Any idea how I can get to the Moped logs in production? I have set logging to debug as described here: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#logging but they don't show up in production.log

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794229/how-do-i-set-the-logging-level-to-info-for-mongodb mongodb logging levels aren't the same as Rails logging levels; make sure you are setting the logging level to debug on your production server.

Comment: After setting the logging level to debug in rails I still don't see any mongoid output on the console. :( I do see however all ActiveRecord sql logs

Comment: Turns out this was simply not working because of Mongodb 1.2 .. updating to 2.0.5 fixed it.. thanks for your help @jcollum

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself..

Turns out Mongodb 1.2.2 from the official Ubuntu repository sources was the problem.
After updating to 2.0.5 everything worked again correctly.