# Ruby on Rails: How can I override a method from a gem while calling the super method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Mongoid::Persistable::Creatable::ClassMethods.module_eval do
  def create(attributes = nil, &block)
    begin
      super
    rescue Mongo::Error::OperationFailure => e
      Rails.logger.error "failed to create notifications #{e.message}, #{e.backtrace}"
      raise
    end
  end
end
```

Hello all, I'm trying to override a method from mongoid gem. So I've implemented the above method in `config/initializers/mongo.rb`, 
expecting my create method to run as defined in the gem, while leaving error log in case it there is a `Mongo::Error::OperationFailure`. But instead it gives me this error.

```
[1] pry(main)> Notification.create(id: 'ididididididid')
NoMethodError: super: no superclass method `create' for Notification:Class
```

I would like to know why this error occurs and how I can fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Just override it in your notification class. But if you use decent development practices this kind of logging is not needed. Use byebug to step into the controller and write tests that cover the validations.

Comment: @max Thanks for the advice. The original problem I have is that I have error log `Mongo::Error::OperationFailure (can't have multiple _id fields in one document (2))` from the moment I updated my Rails application to 5.1. There was no case of such error while using 5.0. So I need to know where this error log is coming from. Any suggestions?

Comment: What method are you trying to override? Given your code doesn't work, it would be much easier for you to provide that information than have us dig through the mongoid source code.

Comment: At a *guess* though, the easiest way would just be to define your own `Notification.create` method!

Comment: You mightg want to create a seperate question about that error - I have not encountered it and it might be bug in mongoid or improper use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794229/how-do-i-set-the-logging-level-to-info-for-mongodb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Monkey patching it directly is hacky and overwrites the method altogether. You expected `super` to call the original implementation, but it is no longer there. Instead create a new module and include it there:

```
module CreateWithErrorLogging
  def create(attributes = nil, &block)
    begin
      super
    rescue Mongo::Error::OperationFailure => e
      Rails.logger.error "failed to create notifications #{e.message}, #{e.backtrace}"
      raise
    end
  end
end

Mongoid::Persistable::Creatable::ClassMethods.include CreateWithErrorLogging
```

Comment: You can also remove the `begin` block and `rescue` the method body.

Comment: @Stefan, I wanted to preserve OP's implementation as not to distract him and other readers from the main point.